# Can someone explain why $z^n= 1$ has exactly $n$ solutions?

Tags: calculus

Proof of $z^n = 1$  has exactly $n$ solutions

Comment: The fundamental algebraic theorem: Any polynomial with degree $n$ has exactly $n$ roots.

Comment: It doesn't, necessarily.

Comment: @rushusuixing Small, pedantic quibble: every polynomial with degree $n$ has *at most* $n$ roots. If you consider polynomials with complex coefficients (and complex roots), then you get exactly $n$ roots *up to multiplicity*. There may be fewer actual numbers that solve the polynomial, however.

Answer (score 2):

To prove that the equation $z^n = 1$ has exactly $n$ solutions in the complex plane, you can use the fact that complex numbers can be represented in polar form. In polar form, a complex number $z$ is expressed as $z = r(\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta))$, where $r$ is the magnitude of $z$ and $\theta$ is the argument (angle) of $z$.

Now, let's consider the equation $z^n = 1$. We want to find all the solutions for $z$. First, we can represent $1$ in polar form:

$1 = 1(\cos(0) + i\sin(0))$

Now, let's represent $z$ in polar form:

$z = r(\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta))$

Substitute this into $z^n = 1$:

$r^n(\cos(n\theta) + i\sin(n\theta)) = 1(\cos(0) + i\sin(0))$

This gives us two equations:

1. $r^n = 1$
2. $n\theta = 0 + 2\pi k$ for some integer $k$

Let's analyze these equations one by one:

1. $r^n = 1$: This equation tells us that $r$ must be $1$ (since $1^n = 1$ for any $n$). This means that all solutions lie on the unit circle in the complex plane.
2. $n\theta = 2\pi k$: This equation tells us that the argument $\theta$ can take on $n$ different values, each separated by $2\pi$ radians. This means there are $n$ distinct solutions for $\theta$:

$$
\theta_1 = \frac{2\pi k}{n},\ \theta_2 = \frac{2\pi (k+1)}{n},\ \theta_3 = \frac{2\pi (k+2)}{n}, \ldots, \theta_n = \frac{2\pi (k+n-1)}{n}
$$

Each of these $\theta$ values corresponds to a distinct complex solution for $z$.

So, combining both equations, there are exactly $n$ solutions for $z^n = 1$, and they are located at equally spaced intervals around the unit circle in the complex plane, with $r = 1$ and different values of $\theta$ given by the $n$ solutions for $\theta$.

Comment: Why we have n distinct solutions for θ

Comment: When you solve $n\theta = 2\pi k$ for $\theta$, you find that $\theta$ can take on multiple values. Specifically, it can be written as:

$
\theta = \frac{2\pi k}{n}
$

Here, as you vary the integer value of $k$ from $0$ to $n-1$, you obtain $n$ distinct values for $\theta$. These values correspond to equally spaced points around the unit circle in the complex plane.

Comment: The answer shows $\theta = \frac{2\pi k}{n}$ for some integer $k$. After $n$, these solutions start repeating. For example, possible values of $\theta$ when $n = 4$ include $$\ldots, -\frac{2\pi}{4}, 0, \frac{4\pi}{4}, \frac{6\pi}{4}, \frac{8\pi}{4}, \frac{10\pi}{4}, \ldots$$But, $\sin$ and $\cos$ repeat every $2\pi$, some of these angles will be the same. For example, $0$ and $\frac{8\pi}{4}$ are really the same (and the same as $\frac{16\pi}{4}$, or $\frac{-8\pi}{4}$. Similarly, $\frac{2\pi}{4}$ produces the same complex number as $\frac{10\pi}{4}$. The same $n$ complex numbers just repeat.